# Почему цикл в потоке не отрабатывает до конца, запись 20 элементов, а прерывается на 7-8 элементах?

Tags: java, многопоточность, sleep

Задача  с JavaRush, она решена но остался вопрос:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

/* 
Magic class
*/
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); /* create object of this magic class here*/;

        solution.startUpdatingThread(list);
        solution.copyOnWriteSolution(list);
        //solution.stopUpdatingThread();
        System.out.println(list);

        /* Example output
size = 0
Element: s781859336
Element: s1453499757
Element: s911312405
Element: s-877520242
Element: s-1636258097
size = 5

Element2: s781859336
Element2: s1453499757
Element2: s911312405
Element2: s-877520242
Element2: s-1636258097
Element2: s-1739827856
Element2: s-938954654
Element2: s925086217
size = 8
         */
    }

    public void copyOnWriteSolution(List<String> list) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
        System.out.println();
        Thread.sleep(20);
        for (String element : list) {   //создает новую копию на момент создания итератора
            System.out.println("Element: " + element);
        }
        System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
        System.out.println();
        Thread.sleep(20);

        for (String element : list) {  //создает новую копию на момент создания итератора
            System.out.println("Element2: " + element);
        }
        System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
//        stopUpdatingThread();
    }

    public void stopUpdatingThread() throws InterruptedException {
        t.stop();
        t.join();
    }

    private Thread t;

    private void startUpdatingThread(final List<String> list) {
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    list.add("s" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Excep");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Не  могу понять, что прекращает дочерний поток startUpdatingThread, что он не успевает дойти до 20.Специально закомитил join, не помогает. Двадцать будет тока, если убрать блок sleep в методе run(),почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t.stop();
```

вот что его останавливает. Хотя метод давно объявлен устаревшим и использовать его не рекомендуется - он выполняет свою функцию, убивает поток (но возможно не в любой реализации VM)

В варианте, когда метод `stopUpdatingThread()` не вызывается (закомментирован) - поток не прекращается и до 20 он доходит. Но у вас нет вывода после завершения цикла - все выводы выполняются раньше и только поэтому вы не видите конечный результат.
Если "дождаться" завершения потока, то в выводе `System.out.println(list);` все 20 будут на месте. Для теста попробуйте так:

```
public void copyOnWriteSolution(List<String> list) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
    System.out.println();
    Thread.sleep(20);
    for (String element : list) {   //создает новую копию на момент создания итератора
        System.out.println("Element: " + element);
    }
    System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
    System.out.println();
    Thread.sleep(20);

    for (String element : list) {  //создает новую копию на момент создания итератора
        System.out.println("Element2: " + element);
    }
    System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
//    stopUpdatingThread();
    t.join(); // ждём завершения потока, не убивая его
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Почему цикл в потоке не отрабатывает до конца, запись 20 элементов, а прерывается на 7-8 элементах?

Потому что поток t к моменту вывода на печать list не успевает наполнить 20 элементов.

У вас есть 2 потока main и t. Поток t наполняет list элементами, поток main печатает эти элементы. И по времени это не согласовано. Поэтому к моменту печати в list оказывается 7-8 элементов, в зависимости от процессора и того как ОС дала ресурсы потоку.
Если вы хотите посмотреть все элементы списка, печатайте их в потоке t после завершения цикла:

```
    import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

/* 
Magic class
*/
public class Solution {
    public static Thread t;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); /* create object of this magic class here*/;

        solution.startUpdatingThread(list);
        solution.copyOnWriteSolution(list);



        /* Example output
size = 0
Element: s781859336
Element: s1453499757
Element: s911312405
Element: s-877520242
Element: s-1636258097
size = 5

Element2: s781859336
Element2: s1453499757
Element2: s911312405
Element2: s-877520242
Element2: s-1636258097
Element2: s-1739827856
Element2: s-938954654
Element2: s925086217
size = 8
         */
    }

    public void copyOnWriteSolution(List<String> list) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
        System.out.println();
        Thread.sleep(20);
        for (String element : list) {   //создает новую копию на момент создания итератора
            System.out.println("Element: " + element);
        }
        System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
        System.out.println();
        Thread.sleep(20);

        for (String element : list) {  //создает новую копию на момент создания итератора
            System.out.println("Element2: " + element);
        }
        System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
//        stopUpdatingThread();
    }

    public void stopUpdatingThread(List<String> list) throws InterruptedException {
        t.interrupt();
        t.join();

    }

  //  private Thread t;

    private void startUpdatingThread(final List<String> list) {
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    list.add("s" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Excep");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (String element : list) {  //печать элементов list

                    System.out.println("Element4: " + element);
                }
                System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
                System.out.println(list);
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Или дождитесь завершения потока перед печатью

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

/* 
Magic class
*/
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); /* create object of this magic class here*/;

        solution.startUpdatingThread(list);
        solution.copyOnWriteSolution(list);
        //solution.stopUpdatingThread();
        System.out.println(list);

        /* Example output
size = 0
Element: s781859336
Element: s1453499757
Element: s911312405
Element: s-877520242
Element: s-1636258097
size = 5

Element2: s781859336
Element2: s1453499757
Element2: s911312405
Element2: s-877520242
Element2: s-1636258097
Element2: s-1739827856
Element2: s-938954654
Element2: s925086217
size = 8
         */
    }

    public void copyOnWriteSolution(List<String> list) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
        System.out.println();
        Thread.sleep(20);
        for (String element : list) {   //создает новую копию на момент создания итератора
            System.out.println("Element: " + element);
        }
        System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
        System.out.println();
        Thread.sleep(20);

        t.join();

        for (String element : list) {  //создает новую копию на момент создания итератора
            System.out.println("Element2: " + element);
        }
        System.out.println("size = " + list.size());
//        stopUpdatingThread();
    }

    public void stopUpdatingThread() throws InterruptedException {
        t.stop();
        t.join();
    }

    private Thread t;

    private void startUpdatingThread(final List<String> list) {
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    list.add("s" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Excep");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```